# Remove the contents of block only 1st and 3rd occurence

Tags: awk, sed

Below sed removes all occurrences of blocks between {content-start} and {content-end}, but want to remove only 1st and 3rd blocks and not 2nd block.

```
sed -ie '/{content-start.*}/,/{content-end}/d' test.txt
```

test.txt:

```
{content-start}
abc1
def1
ghi1
{content-end}
{content-start}
abc2
def2
ghi2
{content-end}
{content-start}
abc3
def3
ghi3
{content-end}
```

Comment: Any reason why just `sed`?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use this file format? Why not json or yaml or even ini file formats?

Comment: sed / awk is fine.  I can not change the file format.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/{content-start}/{x;s/^/x/;x;:a;N;/{content-end}/!ba;x;/^x\{2\}$/{x;p;x};x}' file
```

Use the `-n` option to replicate seds grep-like-nature. Gather up lines between start and end markers. At the start of the collection, append a flag to the hold space to be used as a counter. Having gathered up all the required lines, print only when the hold space contains the required number.

This solution prints only the second block, however if you want to exclude block 1 and block 3 only, then:

```
sed '/{content-start}/{x;s/^/x/;x;:a;N;/{content-end}/!ba;x;/^x\{1\}$/{x;d};/^x\{3\}/{x;d};x}' file
```

This solution deletes block 1 and 3 only.

Answer (score 0):

sed is for simple subsitutions on individual lines, i.e. s/old/new/, **that is all**. For anything else you should be using awk:

```
$ awk '{rec = rec $0 ORS} /{content-end}/{if (++cnt == 2) printf "%s", rec; rec=""}' file
{content-start}
abc2
def2
ghi2
{content-end}
```

or if you're ever going to want to do anything with individual lines then save each line of the record in an array rather than saving the whole record as a string:

```
{ rec[++numLines] = $0 }
/{content-end}/ {
    if ( ++cnt == 2 ) {
        for (lineNr=1; lineNr<=numLines; lineNr++) {
            print rec[lineNr]
        }
    }
    delete rec
    numLines = 0
}
```

The above will work with any awk in any shell on any UNIX system and is trivial to enhance if/when your requirements change.