# Remove particular row values in all blocks using sed

Tags: sed

Remove only 4th and 5th values(fourth1 and fifth1 in 1st block, fourth2 and fifth2 in 2nd block, fourth3 and fifth3 in 3rd block ) in each block.

Tried this `sed -E -e :a -e 's/(.*) ( .*$)/\1 \4 \5/; ta'`  and not working.

```
{content-start}
first1
second1
third1
fourth1
fifth1
sixth1
{content-end}
{content-start}
first2
second2
third2
fourth2
fifth2
sixth2
{content-end}
{content-start}
first3
second3
third3
fourth3
fifth3
sixth3
{content-end}
```

Comment: Stop with the "sed" requirement - it's completely and utterly the wrong tool for any job involving multi-line blocks which is why you have to keep asking new questions for every tiny change in your requirements. You should be using awk - go back and look at the awk answers you already have and just use them for those tasks and make the obvious, trivial tweaks to use them for this and future tasks. People use more than s, g, and p (with -n) in sed just for the mental exercise - every other sed construct became obsolete in the mid 1980s when awk was invented.

Answer (score 1):

Seriously, forget trying to use sed for anything other than simply s/old/new on individual lines. For anything else an awk solution will always be some combination of clearer, simpler, more efficient, easier to enhance/maintain, and more portable than a sed solution for the same task.

This just builds on [my previous awk script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50668784/1745001):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { badLineNrs[5]; badLineNrs[6] }
{ rec[++numLines] = $0 }
/{content-end}/ {
    for (lineNr=1; lineNr<=numLines; lineNr++) {
        if ( !(lineNr in badLineNrs) ) {
            print rec[lineNr]
        }
    }
    delete rec
    numLines = 0
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
{content-start}
first1
second1
third1
sixth1
{content-end}
{content-start}
first2
second2
third2
sixth2
{content-end}
{content-start}
first3
second3
third3
sixth3
{content-end}
```

or if you like brief and cryptic this will also produce the expected output using any awk but it's harder to build on and do things like only print or skip specific records (like in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50659831/1745001)) so other than portability it's not much better than an equivalent sed solution:

```
$ awk '(NR-5)%8 && (NR-6)%8' file
{content-start}
first1
second1
third1
sixth1
{content-end}
{content-start}
first2
second2
third2
sixth2
{content-end}
{content-start}
first3
second3
third3
sixth3
{content-end}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help here too.

```
awk '
/^{content-start}/{
    flag=1;
    print;
    next}
flag{
    count++}
flag && ((count==4) || (count==5)){
    next}
flag;
/^{content-end}/{
    flag=count=""}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Sed for the mental exercice

```
sed -E 'N;N;N;N;N;N;N;s/(([^\n]*\n){4})([^\n]*\n){2}(.*)/\1\4/' infile
```

Comment: or with GNU sed: `sed '5~8d;6~8d' file`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/start/,/end/{/start/{x;s/.*//;x};x;/^x\{4,5\}$/!{x;p;x};s/^/x/;x;b};p' file
```

Turn off automatic printing by setting option `-n`. Focus on lines between `start` and `end` delimiters. Reset a counter to empty if the current line is the `start` delimiter. Print all lines except the fifth and sixth not forgetting to accumulate the counter. Print all other lines.